# Armature Flip Name does not really work (Blender 2.79)

Tags: armature

I duplicated the bone then flip name, but it did not really work.
(Like the attached image below.)

The name of the bone was legUp.L.
After duplicating, the new bone's name was legUp.L.001.
Then I flipped name, and it became legUp.R.001.

Why didn't it remove .001?

[image]

Blender version:2.79

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I notice that flipping names is working different now in 2.79 version.

After some testintgs now I see that it only works using  <kbd>W</kbd>  and selecting **Symetrize**. This really duplicate mirrored and flip the names.

See the image below:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue.  Try this.  Don't duplicate the bones.  Leave them as they are but make sure they are selected. Make sure they are named with an extension that helps blender determine what side in 3D space they occupy. For example .r,.R,_r,.r would all work.  With the bones properly named and selected press "w" on your keyboard and select Symetrize.  This will mirror your bone across the world axes and should rename them without adding the.001 extension.

Comment: thanks but why is symmetrize not flipping the bones across the axis ? I had to mirror them manually (CTRL+M)

Comment: also symmetrize displace the bones so I have to put them back  in place

Answer (score 0):

Because the opposite of xxx.L.001 is xxx.R.001. Blender has no way of knowing that you follow a "duplicate, flip, rename" approach to create the right-hand side of the armature, and thus the Flip Name operator does only that: flip the name.

Comment: I think he was referring to this manual page https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/rigging/armatures/bones/editing/naming.html which says "You can copy a bone named “bla.L” and flip it over using Specials ‣ Flip Left-Right Names. Blender will name the copy “bla.L.001” and flipping the name will give you “bla.R”."

Comment: Yap. I took blender manual page as reference.

Comment: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/armatures/bones/editing/naming.html "Before Blender handles an armature for mirroring or flipping, it first removes the number extension, e.g. “.001”."