# Mirroring bones not working correctly

Tags: mesh, rigging, armature, bones, mirror

Hello I am having problems with my rigging in blender.

[image: Left arm moves both sides of mesh]

as you can see rotating my left arm rotates both the left and right arm, but when I rotate just the right arm it doesn't move any of the mesh.

[image: left leg moves both sides of mesh]

I dont know how to fix this and was hoping someone could help me out.

[image: Right arm rotate bone]

I used a mirror modifier to mirror the whole right side of my character, and I think this is causing the problem but I dont know how to fix it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Armature Flip Name does not really work (Blender 2.79)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/92866/armature-flip-name-does-not-really-work-blender-2-79)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to let mirrored half move independently](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/121540/how-to-let-mirrored-half-move-independently)

Answer (score 1):

Fixed my problem, the mirrored bones were given a name with .001 at the end.
I took the .001 off every mirrored bone and it fixed my issue.